# How to get all documents from the data bucket using c#?

Tags: c#, nosql, couchbase

How can I get all the documents from the data bucket?

I have tried a sample but I'm able to get only a specific document. Here is my code:

```
CouchbaseClient oclient;

oclient= new CouchbaseClient("vwspace", "");// data bucket name

var results = oclient.Get("205");// document id
```

How to get all the documents?

```
var results = oclient.? //what should i use here to get all documents
```

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784283/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-keys-documents-in-couchbase-database-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 5):

Using Couchbase Server 2.0, you would use a view to get all documents.  Your view would look like:

```
function (doc, meta) {
   emit(null, null);
}
```

This view will give you access to all of the ids (id is always included in non-reduced view query results).

For more on views and querying views in .NET, see http://blog.couchbase.com/strongly-typed-views-net-client-library.

Comment: Will this give me access to the design documents also..?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get all documents. Create one "constant" atomic integer value that will be `counter` like this:

```
CouchbaseClient oclient;

oclient= new CouchbaseClient("vwspace", "");// data bucket name

ulong results = (ulong)oSourceBucket.Get("MYCOUNTER");// counter (integer incremental value)
```

When you add documents to bucket don't add them with some documentId (I suppose you get that form SQL database or something) but make them with `counter` like this:

```
results = oSourceBucket.Increment("MYCOUNTER", results, 1);// counter (integer incremental value)

oSourceBucket.Store(StoreMode.Add, "MYITEM." + results.toString(), myNewObjectToStore);
```

Now you can just use `for` loop to `oSourceBucket.Get(...)` all items up until `MYCOUNTER` value. I am not sure if new version of Couchbase 2.0 will have pattern gets but current stable version (1.8.1 I think) allows only exact key gets.

Remeber this is KEY-VALUE store, not SQL :)

Also there is `MultiGet` in Couchbase but in last stable version of .NET client it does not exist but it is used under the hood just like `for...` loop with multiple `Get`-s.

Comment: oSourceBucket.Store(StoreMode.Add, "MYITEM." + results.toString(), myNewObjectToStore);

what does myNewObjectToStore specify? pls clarify this as i'm new to this..

Comment: myNewObjectToStore is object that you wish to store to Couchbase, in this case your document :)

Comment: I'm having 5 documents.. I don't need to add new doc.. all i need is jus access those 5 documents..can i get all those 5 documents.. Is that can be achieved with ur code.. If possible jus share me the code..

Comment: BTW, Multiget is supported in the Couchbase .NET Client Library - it's CouchbaseClient.Get(IEnumerable<string> key);

Comment: @JohnZablocki yes but under the hood (in the library) it is just multiple gets in a loop. Real multiget is single command sent to Couchbase that was/is not implemented in client library.

Comment: @Xavier I told you, your method that stores those documents is wrong. But if you know all 5 IDs you can just use it as John said above, but your approach to this is not best practice.

Comment: @lord.fist that's not quite accurate.  The CouchbaseClient (via Enyim), uses GetQ operations.  The loop under the hood isn't a get-per-key, it's a GetQ-per-node.  So if you had 10 keys that were located across 3 nodes, the client would make 3 parallel GetQ requests, not 10 Get requests.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a couchbase view that emits document id ( meta.id ).

Or use existing view that emits every record.

Then

```
http://HOST:8092/YOURBUCKETNAME/_design/YOURDESIGNDOCNAME/_view/YOURVIEWNAME?reduce=false&limit=10
```

You'll get result like the following

```
{"total_rows":1321085,"rows":[
{"id":"key1","key": ... ,"value": ... },
{"id":"key2","key": ... ,"value": ... },
{"id":"key3","key": ... ,"value": ... },
...
]
}
```

The "id" field contains document key.

You'll need to paginate over the results.
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-writing-querying-pagination.html